# Java / Converting from Observable<List<String>> to List<String>

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, blocking, builder

I have a result set from SQL Query

```
Builder object_key = db.select(String.format("select object_key from "
+ CAMPAIGN_TABLE));
```

that returns a `Builder` data type. I need to store the output of the SQL Query in `List<String> object_key_list`. I am not sure how to do that. Can anyone be able to help me with it?

1. If I call

   object_key.autoMap(String.class);

then that returns an `Observable<String>` data type.

2. If I call

   object_key.autoMap(String.class).toList();

then that returns an `Observable<List<String>>` data type.

3. If I call

   object_key.autoMap(String.class).toList().toBlocking();

then that returns an `BlockingObservable<List<String>>` data type.

4. If I call

   object_key.autoMap(String.class).toList().toSingle();

then that returns an `Single<List<String>>` data type.

How is it possible to get a `List<String>` value for `object_key_list` as a returned data type?

By the way, what is that confusing enough `Observable` as a returned data type first of all?

Comment: It is possible for me to convert from `Builder` to `List<String>` by using `object_key.getAs(String.class).toList().toBlocking().single();`.

Comment: While the other type of error namely something like: `2018-12-07 15:14:14.540::[ERROR]::[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0]::RequestHandlerVerticleImpl::getDynamicAdResponse failed : constructor with number of parameters=22  not found in class com.samsung.dsp.models.CampaignData` that it occurs when if the number of columns that are selected from the database does not match with the number of columns passed within whatever that into the constructor function of `CampaignData` class in these various cases anyway.

Comment: Or that it occurs when if the data of device that are available in the database does not match with the values of device that are passed within whatever that into the different functions of project in another available cases anyway in another word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to your observable, e.g.:

```
Observable<List<String>> o = Observable.empty();
// ....
o.subscribe(strings -> {
  // strings is list you are looking for
});
```

After you subscribe, whenever you get result from your db, you would be notified and you can do something with your list of string. I hope it would help.

Comment: What is the difference between `object_key.getAs(String.class).toList().toBlocking().single();` and `object_key.autoMap(String.class).toList().toBlocking().single();`? It seems that the former statement works out for me perfectly enough after all, while the latter statement does not work out for me properly enough at all?

Comment: I am not that familiar with rxjdbc (I guess), but what is the problem with second statement, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I am not sure about it but I am getting `InvocationTargetException` caught in `run()` function of `ReflectiveCallable` class. I am getting the following error message: `java.lang.RuntimeException: problem with parameters=java.lang.String=1536129293665-empty_test_file_apk.txt, rs types=apk_s3_objectkey=java.lang.String. Be sure not to use primitives in a constructor when calling autoMap()`.

Comment: Or in another word, this error usually happens when some of the date fields in database are null or data types of attributes passed in a function do not match with the data types that are present and available in the database.

Comment: It might be helpful to look at code: https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-jdbc. Find class Util which arise this exception. the exception is related to invoke constructor of String for wrong parameters.